# Jest test: Cannot find module, in typescript component import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, next.js

The path to my styled objects is correct, however not sure why I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot find module '../../shared/models' from 'Astronaut.tsx'
>
> import { moonHoldings } from '../../shared/models';

My simple Jest test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';

// @ts-ignore (works with .tsx)
import Astronaut from '../Astronaut.tsx';

describe('<Astronaut /> component', () => {
  describe('should render', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Astronaut showLogo={true} />);
    it ('should render a component matching the snapshot', () => {
      const tree = toJson(wrapper);
      expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
      expect(wrapper).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });
});
```

The Astronaut component

```
import React from 'react';

import { moonHoldings } from '../../shared/models';  // <-- The problem
import { astronaut } from '../../styles'; // <-- This works

const { AstronautContainer, Heading } = astronaut;

interface LogoCheck {
  showLogo: boolean;
}

export default (showLogo: LogoCheck) =>  (
  <AstronautContainer>
    { showLogo.showLogo === true ? <Heading>{moonHoldings}</Heading> : null }
    <img src="static/astronaut.png" alt="astronaut" />
  </AstronautContainer>
);
```

The Jest config section of my Package.json

```
"jest": {
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js",
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/.next/",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "\\.(gql|graphql)$": "jest-transform-graphql",
    ".*": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "ts",
    "tsx"
  ],
  "modulePaths": [
    "<rootDir>/components/",
    "<rootDir>/pages/",
    "<rootDir>/shared/"
  ]
}
```

And my folder structure:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just fixed this by created an index file inside of the /shared folder and then exporting out the models that way (Though it should have still worked without the index file):

`import { moonHoldings } from '../../shared';`

[image]

And the index.js:

```
export { moonHoldings, nomicsLink } from './copy';
```

Comment: Did you import them then in the jest test file

Comment: This seems more like a workaround than an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do little configuration for your jest test.
Adding this snippet to your `package.json` should allow you to take your custom name and map it to your actual folder:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^@fooBar/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/barFoo/$1"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got this error in a lot of instances inside my test file and the solution was to use file paths based mapping in the `moduleNameMapper` option inside my jest.config file. This helps us to map our absolute paths with their corresponding relative ones.

For example, if you are getting this error -

```
  ● Test suite failed to run
                                                                                                                                                             
    Cannot find module 'jsroot/io' from 'src/some-file.ts'
```

Adding this should work -

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    // 'absolute-path': 'relative-path'
    'jsroot/io': '<rootDir>/node_modules/jsroot/',
},
```

where `<rootDir>` is the root of the directory containing your Jest config file or the package.json.